# Is there a way to use NSNotificationCenter in cocoa library?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a cocoa framework. In that framework I want to add some Notification code so that if time or date changes it can perform some operations. I have following code for notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleSysTimeChanged:)
      name:NSSystemClockDidChangeNotification object:nil];

-(void) handleSysTimeChanged: (NSNotification*) notification

{

    //some operation

}
```

please any one tell me ,Is it possible to perform this through framework? if YES then how? if NO then why?

Comment: don't get your problem

Comment: i want to use above code in cocoa framework for getting time/date change notification, but i don't know how to use this code in framework.@Daij-Djan